# Group array some values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hi
I'm trying to display Array that has the same type but different value.
How can I show this array in a grouped way according to the value "CAT"?

My array:

```
$options  = array(
    array("cat" => "Impresoras","nameProd" => "Impresora 4"),
    array("cat" => "Destructoras","nameProd" => "Destructora 3"),
    array("cat" => "Impresoras","nameProd" => "Impresora 8"),
    array("cat" => "Destructoras","nameProd" => "Destructora 5")
);
```

I need print:

Impresoras: Impresora 4, Impresora 8
Destructoras: Destructora 3, Destructora 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
  $options  = array(
    array("cat" => "Impresoras","nameProd" => "Impresora 4"),
    array("cat" => "Destructoras","nameProd" => "Destructora 3"),
    array("cat" => "Impresoras","nameProd" => "Impresora 8"),
    array("cat" => "Destructoras","nameProd" => "Destructora 5")
  );

  foreach ($options as $key => $value) {    
    $nArray[$value['cat']][] =  $value['nameProd'];      
  }
  foreach ($nArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.":".implode(",", $value)."<br>";
  }
```

**Output**

```
Impresoras:Impresora 4,Impresora 8
Destructoras:Destructora 3,Destructora 5
```

Comment: Output:
Impresoras:Impresora 4,Impresora 8
Destructoras:Destructora 3,Destructora 5
Impresoras:Impresora 4,Impresora 8,Impresora 4,Impresora 8
Destructoras:Destructora 3,Destructora 5,Destructora 3,Destructora 5
Impresoras:Impresora 4,Impresora 8,Impresora 4,Impresora 8,Impresora 4,Impresora 8
Destructoras:Destructora 3,Destructora 5,Destructora 3,Destructora 5,Destructora 3,Destructora 5

Comment: Ok, your code is perfect, I was programming it in a while. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array with the `cat` as key. Someting like this;

```
$grouped_categories = array();
foreach ( $options as $option ) {
    $grouped_categories[$option['cat']][] = $option['nameProd'];
}
```

This will output something like;

```
[
    'Impresoras' => ['Impresora 4', 'Impresora 8']
    'Destructoras' => [...]
]
```

How you want to output that array is up to you.

Comment: Output:Impresora 4
Destructora 3
Impresora 8
Destructora 5
Impresora 4
Destructora 3
Impresora 8
Destructora 5
Impresora 4
Destructora 3
Impresora 8
Destructora 5

Answer (score 0):

```
    $data = [];
    $options = array(
        array("cat" => "Impresoras", "nameProd" => "Impresora 4"),
        array("cat" => "Destructoras", "nameProd" => "Destructora 3"),
        array("cat" => "Impresoras", "nameProd" => "Impresora 8"),
        array("cat" => "Destructoras", "nameProd" => "Destructora 5")
    );

    foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
        $data[$value['cat']][] = $value['nameProd'];
    };
```